# Bisect search using varying hi lo

Tags: python, search, bisect

I am trying to figure out how to use a bisect search to find:

Monthly payment made to clear loan amount

- Monthly interest rate = (Annual interest rate) / 12
- Monthly payment lower bound = Balance / 12
- Monthly payment upper bound = (Balance x (1 + Monthly interest rate)12) / 12

At the moment I have:

```
balance = 6758
annualInterestRate = 0.20
monthlyRate = annualInterestRate/12
numGuesses = 0
lo = balance/12
hi = (balance)*((1+monthlyRate)**12)/12
monthPay = (hi + lo)/2.0
NuBalance = balance
while abs((NuBalance)*(1+monthlyRate))-(monthPay) >= 0.01:
    print('low = ' + str(lo) + ' high = ' + str(hi) + ' MonthPay = ' + str(monthPay))
    numGuesses += 1
    if ((NuBalance)*(1+monthlyRate))-(monthPay) <= 0.01:
        print('Month Pay LO = ' + str(monthPay))
        lo = monthPay
    else:
        print('Month Pay HI = ' + str(monthPay))
        hi = monthPay
    monthPay = (hi + lo)/2.0
print('numGuesses = ' + str(numGuesses))
print('Month Pay = ' + str(monthPay))
```

Any help to where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: it doesnt calculate the search correctly, It keeps using hi to bisect and decreases on itself when it should use lo sometimes to use the correct half of the bisect.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
while abs((NuBalance)*(1+monthlyRate)-(monthPay)) >= 0.01:
                                    ^           ^
```

and always exists

```
(hi + lo)/2.0 < (NuBalance)*(1+monthlyRate)
```

is `True` because `hi` and `lo` both smaller than `(NuBalance)*(1+monthlyRate)`

```
In [9]: print 'lo:', lo
lo: 563

In [10]: print 'hi:', hi
hi: 686.720412649

In [11]: print 'monthPay:', monthPay
monthPay: 624.860206325

In [12]: print '(NuBalance)*(1+monthlyRate):', (NuBalance)*(1+monthlyRate)
(NuBalance)*(1+monthlyRate): 6870.63333333
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I see where I made the mistake with the math, I'm not sure I still quite understand.

Comment: I need calculate the mid 'monthPay' over 12 months and see if it has reduced the balance to 0.01 taking into account the interest as the balance drops. then repeat each time using the bisect search to give me a new 'monthPay'. then output the result